# Slow hive query, why (left-semi-join)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My hive query is hanging and I don't know why (using hadoop 0.20.1, hive 0.9).

Query:

```
SELECT 
   a.field1 FROM table_1 a 
LEFT SEMI JOIN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT(usrId) FROM table_2 b 
       WHERE soemthing=true ORDER BY rand() limit 1000) random_user_ids 
WHERE a.usrId=random_user_ids.usrId
```

EXPLAIN gives me back:

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-2 depends on stages: Stage-1
  Stage-3 depends on stages: Stage-2
  Stage-0 is a root stage
```

Data-Set

- ~200M entries inside table
- the relation of table_1.usrId to table_1 should be about 1:40, i.e. 1000*40=40000 should be returned in above query

Observations:

- Job hangs at final Stage-3 at 33% (reduce > sort), where the joining is happening (join result is about 40000)
- Apart from being slow why is reduce > sort part of Stage-3 at all? It should only join stuff not ORDER anything
- reducer size is only 1 (because of sort?), which is nearly always bad as it doesn't scale.

If you need more input (e.g. more verbose EXPLAIN info, more cluster info) just tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JOIN condition should be included in an **ON** clause, not in the WHERE clause.

Example of syntax:

```
SELECT a.key, a.val
FROM a LEFT SEMI JOIN b ON (a.key = b.key)
```

Comment: aargh, the ON that made the trick. still with 'WHERE' a mistery why reduce operator was sort on Stage-3, coulnd't see it with EXPLAIN plan.